# Post Value To MVC Action Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following JQuery code which retrieves the value from a hidden text box within my MVC 5 Razor View once a submit button is clicked.

```
$('#mySubmit').click(function() {

    //Get the id to delete from the hidden field
    var id = $('#item-to-delete').val();

    window.location.href = "/CSurvey/Delete/" + id;

});
```

I then want to POST this value to a HttpPost Action within my Controller. I have tried the code above but it states it cannot find the page and I think this is because my redirect to the Controller Action is incorrect.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int AssessorID)
{
    //delete code
}
```

Does anyone know of another way to pass the value to the Controller Action?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to post a form, set the `action` to the action url. Or you could send it with an XHR call.

Comment: @Johan Could you provide some sample code on how to set the action to the action url? Or maybe pass a link where this is already shown. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, would you like it to be async?

Comment: @Johan Without async would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefarably, you would like to send a `DELETE` request to the server.

However, since you're using a `<form>`, you'll only have access to `GET` and `POST`. A html forms default `method` is `POST`. Thus, we need to specify `GET` explicitly:

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="item-to-delete"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){

    e.preventDefault(); // don't submit the form... yet

    var $this = $(this),
        id = $this.find('#item-to-delete').val();

    if(!+id) return; // get the id and make sure it's an integer

    $this.prop({ action: '/CSurvey/Delete/' + id }); // set the form action

    $this.submit(); // submit the form with the correct action
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try the following code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/CSurvey/Delete",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: {AssessorID=id},
  success: function() { window.location.href = "to/where/you/like"},
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        $("#DeleteBtn").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/CSurvey/Delete/",
                data: { id: $("#id").val() }


            }).done(function (msg) {
                 alert(msg);
                location.reload();



            });
        })
```

You can pass your Id and then delete using Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

try this

instead of `post` use `get` since you are not posting any data

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete(int AssessorID)
{
    //delete code
}
```

Comment: You should never make delete operations with a `GET` request.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use: $('#form').serialize()

Please refer here: http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/how-and-when-to-use-jquerys-serialize-method/